AWS Event Bridge - how to save meta data on the rule?
I have an API endpoint, where I create a scheduled rule e.g. "website-a-scrape-weekly". As a target I set a lambda that needs some additional data. I have passed down the json with this data so that I can directly access it in my lambda when is being invoked.
Problem:
Is there an easy way of also setting some meta data on the rule rather then the target? I am trying to query all rules in my dashboard and I need that data from the target.
Thanks
I know that for each rule I query, i can also query its targets, find the lambda one, get json and return together with the rule details. Is there an alternative way where I can prevent from listing all targets every time I query the rules?
Also, i have considered syncing it with a DB but it seems like an overkill for just trying to get rule's meta data.

This implies that the meta-data value(s) you need on the rule would be the same for all targets, is that correct? If yes, then could you make use of rule tags or key value storage based on the rule name?

@RossBush that's correct. I want to have only one target assign to a rule. So basically to sync it with e.g. DynamoDB? I have thought about that, but I was not sure how to handle e.g. if I delete rule from the AWS console then I would still have the outdated rule it in my db. Would rule tags work for more complex data like arrays?

Tags would not be a good fit for large values. The documented number of tags per resource is 50 with a key length of 128 and max value length of 256. Tags appear to be more of an organizational mechanism rather than a source for persistent storage. There are ways to react to resource removal events, including rule removal, however, each level of abstraction requires another level of indirection.

@RossBush that explains it well. Thank you
